# Strange results when I call a C ++ class method inside an openmp loop

Tags: c++, openmp

Good Morning people.

I made a code that run in a single thread mode and I'm trying to adapt it in a multiple threads mode. 
I'm running a method quite similar to the MARCH::RUN_PAR in single thread mode with good results, but when I'm trying to execute in a multiple threads mode (using Openmp) the results are too strange.

Someone can help me in this question?

Follow bellow my piece of code:

```
void MI_MARCH::RUN_PARALELO(double zt,double ***Vpar,int mt,int red_yred,int prof,int tam) {

        int RANK, numero_proc_parall;
        int shift,cont,m,rredy;
        //start the number of (possible) threads
        numero_proc_parall = tam;   
        //shift the loop of threads
        shift = 0;
        //the necessary total number of threads
        cont = prof;
        //set the number of threads
        omp_set_num_threads(numero_proc_parall);    
        //argument initialization    
        rredy = red_yred;   

        MARCH VETOR_MARCH[numero_proc_parall];  //vector of class   

        //open the parallel section
        #pragma omp parallel shared(cont,shift,numero_proc_parall) private(red_yred,RANK,m)
        {

            while(cont > 0)
            {

                #pragma omp critical
                std::cout<<"[MI_MARCH RUN_PAR] loop cont "<<cont<<" shift "<<shift<<" numero_proc_parall "<<numero_proc_parall<<"\n";           
                #pragma omp for
                for(m=0;m<numero_proc_parall;m++) //loop de profundidade
                {
                    //atualize the rank 
                    RANK = omp_get_thread_num();
                    //set the reference
                    red_yred = rredy + m + shift            
                    //run the method of the MARCH class
                    VETOR_MARCH[m].RUN_PAR(zt,Vpar[m],mt,red_yred,RANK + shift);                
                }   
                //execute only in the master thread
                #pragma omp master
                {
                    //increment the shift variable
                    shift = shift + numero_proc_parall;
                    //decrement the loop control
                    cont = cont - numero_proc_parall;
                    //verify if the process is greater than controller  
                    if(cont<numero_proc_parall)
                    {
                        //set a new number of parallel process
                        numero_proc_parall = cont;
                    }                               
                }
                #pragma omp barrier //waiting other process
            }       
        }
    }
```

The MARCH::RUN_PAR method is:

```
    void MARCH::RUN_PAR(double zt,double **Vxy,int mt,int red_yred,int RANK);
    {

        int xf,yf;    
        xf = 100;
        yf = 100; 

        //execute this piece of code in critical mode
        #pragma omp critical
        {       

            for(int i=0;i<xf;i++)
            {
                 for(int j=0;j<yf;j++)
                {           
                    Vcopia[i][j] = Vxy[i][j];  //Vcopia is a member of MARCH class
                }
            }

        }

        V_H(Vcopia,xf,yf,red_yred); //this method is a member of MARCH class

        CALC(mt,zt,RANK); //this method is a member of MARCH class

    }

...
    class MARCH{
    public: 
    ...
      void RUN_PAR(double zt,double **Vxy,int mt,int red_yred,int RANK);

    private:    
    ...
      double **Vcopia;
    ...
      void V_H(double **Vcopia,int xf,int yf,int red_yred); 

      void CALC(int mt,double zt,int RANK); 
    };
```

The incorrect results, apparently, are appearing in a sequential mode.

The correct result in a single thread mode is a image like this: [correct image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHgkm.png)

The incorrect using multiple threads is a image like this: [incorrect image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCA0D.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: can you include the prototype of `RUN_PAR` ?

Comment: Please consider the differences between processes and threads. OpenMP uses the threads, **not** processes. This makes your question difficult to understand.

Comment: Can you include the definition of `Vcopia`? And are you sure that semicolon after `void MARCH::RUN_PAR(double zt,double **Vxy,int mt,int red_yred,int RANK)` and before the `{` isn't causing a problem?